# DMS Task is failing with Invalid LSN for DB2 LUW

Tags: amazon-web-services, db2, dms

I have set up AWS DMS CDC Task with DB2 LUW Server. When I restart or resume a new CDC task it gets failed and gives below error.

We have confirmed that there are no changes occur at DB2. There was one more CDC task for the same source was running fine. By mistake, I have deleted that also and have created exact same Task for all same tables again but now it starts giving me the same error which was giving me for another CDC task for the same source. This issue starts occurring suddenly.

> Last Error Error reading the database log. Task error notification
> received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:xxxx]
> [xxxxx] Error at 'Reading log records': Trying to read an invalid LSN
> from the DB2 LUW log. Original SQLCODE -2650: ' message SQL2650N An
> invalid parameter "piStartLSN" was passed to the "db2ReadLog" read log
> API. Reason Code = "4". ., SQLSTATE '; scan_log_timestamps: Error
> reading next buffer; capture_start: Error creating timestamp mapping
> table; Error executing command; Stream component failed at subtask 0,
> component st_0_P4RZFVKJAM4AZEPZWFKKZVQWWHYRSBKKWTZBCXQ ; Stream
> component 'st_0_P4RZFVKJAM4AZEPZWFKKZVQWWHYRSBKKWTZBCXQ' terminated
> [reptask/replicationtask.c:xxx] [xxxxx] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error
> Level FATAL

I know the description of SQLCODE and Reason Code but not getting why it is giving error. I am new for DB2. Could you please help to get a possible solution and cause at DB2 or DMS end.

**Note:** Issue is occurring with this source only and it is giving exact same error for all CDC tasks. Full Load tasks are running perfectly.

DB2 Version: ***DB2 v9.7.0.2 with Fix Pack 2***

Comment: Refer to the whoever supports the Amazon DMD CDC for Db2.  This is unlikely to be a matter for Stackoverflow. The code is not specifying a correct LSN when it retstarts.

Comment: @mao, thank you for the reply. I Support DMS, How AWS DMS Capture LSN that is not documented. I wanted help from DB2 perspective if somebody knows this issue exactly and also knows what is that possible cause, it will help me to convey a message to DB2 guy who can check this issue.

Comment: The probable cause is a code defect in the software that calls the db2ReadLog API.  You need to raise a ticket with who-ever wrote or maintains that code, giving a recreatable scenario that shows the symptom.